# How to extract multiple cells from an excel file using javascript on one function. (if possible)

Tags: javascript, html, excel

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Style Get data from excel sheet
</title>
<script language="javascript" >
function GetData(cell,row){
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("I:test.xlsx");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
document.getElementById('div1').innerText =data;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="background: #009955; width:'100%';" align="center">
<font color="#000080" size="12pt">
<b>Get data from excel sheets</b>
</font>
</div>
<center>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="div1" style="background: #DFDFFF; width:'100%';" align="center">
Click buttons to fetch data from F:\\test.xls
</div>
<input type="button" value="cell(1),row(1)" onClick="GetData(1,1);" />
<input type="button" value="cell(2),row(1)" onClick="GetData(1,2);" />
<input type="button" value="cell(1),row(2)" onClick="GetData(2,1);" />
<input type="button" value="cell(2),row(2)" onClick="GetData(2,2);" />
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this several times and I'm afraid I cannot explain myself very well so I found this generic code from this site that does almost exactly what I need it to do. The only thing is that I need it to get multiple cells from an excel file "onclick". As you can see, its only getting it from i.e. (1,1) but how would I write it if I wanted all of them (1,1)(1,2)(2,1)(2,2) to be gathered with only one button or a href? I know this must be easy to you guys but I'm new at this. Two weeks new. So please, any help would be appreciated. :) (And I've tried to play with it changing code here and there, but nada.)

Answer (score 7):

Simplest example...

```
function gbid(s){return document.getElementById(s);}

function GetData(cell,row){
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("I:\\test.xlsx");
    var sht = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");

    gbid('div1').innerText = sht.Cells(1,1).Value;
    gbid('div2').innerText = sht.Cells(1,2).Value;
    gbid('div3').innerText = sht.Cells(2,1).Value;
    gbid('div4').innerText = sht.Cells(2,2).Value;
}
```

To extract a range:

```
var v = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1,1), sht.Cells(10,10)).Value;
//or
var v = sht.Range("A1:J10").Value;
```

Comment: That's it! This is perfect! Too bad I'm gonna have to write a gang of functions for all the links on the page! lol, wish there was an easier way. Well, I'm sure there is but I'm on a deadline and cant study further! Thank you much Tim! You saved me! I cant write a positive on the number thinggy but my rep is too low! I hope someone else can do it for me. Thanx again!

Comment: No problem - don't forget (as I did) to Close the Excel file when you're done copying data.

Comment: is that, Application.quit or Excel.application.close? Sorry, did not even know when working with Javascript we had to close them

Comment: To be safe: `excel_file.Close()` and then `excel.Quit()`

Comment: Didn't work. I forgot to check the 'processes' tab in the Task Manager but when I did, there was over 75 excel docs still open. I'm putting it at the end of the function, am I putting it in the wrong place? I've always put close.files at the end until it was a file that needed to be loaded, then it would go in the front so no errors happen. but thats VB. Headache? I mean, any ideas?

Comment: @Tim Williams :  Is there any option to set value to a range of cells?? Or I just have to loop it ??

Comment: ActiveXObject is not available for Chrome. How do I use this for Google Chrome?